# Using array init list as temporary in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I can create a named variable with an array as follows:

```
char s[] = {1, 2, 3, 0};
if (strcmp(s, t))
    ...
```

However the following doesn't work:

```
if (strcmp(char[]{1,2,3,0}, t))
    ...
```

Is there some way to specify a temporary unnamed array with an initializer list? (In this case a string literal would work, but for arrays other than char arrays?)

**Update:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

typedef char CA[];

int main()
{
        cout << CA{1,2,3, 0} << endl;
}
```

gives `error: taking address of temporary array` (`g++-4.7.2 -std=gnu++11`)

**Update 2:**

I think (maybe) what is happening is that string literals are specially blessed as *lvalues*, however temporary arrays are *prvalues*, and as such you cant take their address.  This is a wild guess though, I'm not sure.

**Update 3:**

Actually that should be wrong I think:

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue
>   of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: What would be the advantage of using an unnamed temporary array instead of a named constant? It doesn't do much for readability.

Comment: "Is there some way to specify a temporary unnamed array with an initializer list?" Well, aside from the `typedef` stuff already answered below, `std::initializer_list` does exactly this, if you're passing it to something that can handle any range or has a specific overload.

Answer (score 15):

1) I suffered with this problem for some time. Compiling the following program, g++ 4.7.1 (tdm64-1) gives the error: "teste1.cpp:6:33: error: taking address of temporary array"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ char t[]={1,2,3,0};
  if (strcmp((char[]){1,2,3,0},t)==0)  //error
    cout << "equal\n";
  else 
    cout << "different\n";
}
```

However, if you add the keyword "const", the error disappears and the program runs smoothly:

```
if (strcmp((const char[]){1,2,3,0},t)==0) //correct
```

2) In some cases, just adding the keyword "const" may not be enough. For example, g++ 4.7.1 gives "error: taking address of temporary array" when compiling the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void f(char* p)
{ for (int i=0; p[i]!=0; i++) 
    cout << int(p[i]) << " ";
  cout << endl;
}

int main() {
  f((char[]){1,2,3,0}); // error
}
```

If you add the keyword "const", the compiler gives another kind of error: "invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]":

```
f((const char[]){1,2,3,0}); //error
```

To successfully compile the program, you can either compile it with option "-fpermissive" or make a explicit type conversion:

```
f((char*)(const char[]){1,2,3,0}); // correct
```

Comment: const casting like that is ugly, besides invalidating the use and purpose of const.

Comment: This may work for some g++ version, but bear in mind this solution is not well-formed C++ (`(char[]){1,2,3,0}` <- compound literals are C>=99 but not allowed in C++, and the syntax is not allowed to introduce a temporary in C++, see [my comment to Johannes' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458883/using-array-init-list-as-temporary-in-c11#comment24292271_15458897)). Modifying the passed `const char[]` would introduce undefined behaviour. In this example, `f` does not modify the parameter, therefore the function signature should be `void f(const char*);`.

Comment: Indeed, my solution compiles and executes correctly in g++ but not in Visual C.

Comment: Also, be aware that compound literals in C and the C++ extension that allows you to use compound literal syntax often differ; specifically, a compound literal is valid for the entire block it is contained in, so e.g. `struct foo *f = &(struct foo){...};` is valid C, provided the pointer does not escape the block where the compound literal occurs, while in C++, the Clang version of this extension simply to allows you to use this syntax to declare a temporary object, whose lifetime is only that of the expression it belongs to, like C++ temporaries declared the standard way (without parentheses).

Comment: I think that may be related to the choice g++ makes to give an error here: you're using non-standard syntax that looks like a C compound literal, but that is a C++ temporary object, and they might worry that you think the taken address will remain valid for longer than it actually will. That is, assuming the g++ extension has the same semantics as the Clang extension, but given the extent to which Clang pursues compatibility with gcc, that seems likely.

Answer (score 6):

Yes use a typedef and then say

```
ArrayType{1, 2, 3, 0}
```

Alternatively use an alias template and then

```
AliasTemplate<char[]>{1, 2, 3, 0}
```

Comment: @user great, that is what you wanted! if you want to understand why this warning is given, i recommend a second question.

Comment: @user1131467 It works with clang++3.2, I guess it's a g++ bug (should be a warning). See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53220)

Comment: Let's add some references: [expr.type.conv]/3 & 1 (can use `simple-type-id{ expression-list }` to introduce a temporary); [dcl.type.simple]/1 (cannot use `char[]` but `typedef char ArrayType[]; ArrayType{ expression-list }` because `char[]` is not a simple-type-id but `ArrayType` is). g++4.8 is wrong (Johannes' solution is well-formed), clang++3.2 is right (again)

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this problem can be solved using C++11 "move". Compiling in g++ 4.8.1 the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

typedef char CA[];
int main() {
  cout << CA{'a','b','c',0} << endl;
}
```

results in "error: taking address of temporary array". However, using "move":

```
cout << move(CA{'a','b','c',0}) << endl;
```

the program compiles and runs correctly. The compiler must be invoked to use C++11 dialect:

```
g++ prog1.cpp -o prog.exe -std=c++11
```

Similarly,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ char t[]={1,2,3,0};
  if (strcmp( move((char[]){1,2,3,0}) ,t)==0)  //OK
    cout << "equal\n";
  else 
    cout << "different\n";
}
```

also compiles and runs correctly, using -std=c++11 flag.