# Initialise static class member of type vector

Tags: c++, arrays, static, instance-variables

I have a class with a private static instance variable of type vector >. I had a strategy for initialising this variable that involved passing a temporary array to a function that was not a class member. This worked on older versions of g++, but not with g++ 4.8.2.

Here's what I'm doing:

initclass.cpp:

```
#include "initclass.h"

#define NINT 5

vector<pair<int,int> > initInstance(const pair<int,int> *array, int nint)
{
  vector<pair<int,int> > vect;
  vect.assign(array, array + nint);

  return vect;
}

const vector<pair<int,int> > initclass::_intvect = 
  initInstance((pair<int,int>[NINT]){pair<int,int>(1,2), pair<int,int>(3,4), 
                                     pair<int,int>(5,6), pair<int,int>(7,8), 
                                     pair<int,int>(9,10)}, 
    NINT);
```

initclass.h:

```
#ifndef INITCLASS_H_
#define INITCLASS_H_

#include <utility>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class initclass
{
public:      
  static const vector<pair<int,int> > & intvect() { return _intvect; };

private:
  const static vector<pair<int,int> > _intvect;      
};

#endif
```

I can make this work by just declaring the array of pair objects before calling the initInstance function, but I'm wondering if there's a better way (this is of course a simplified example of what I'm trying to do: in my real code, there are many calls to the initialisation function with many arrays, and I'd rather not declare each of them prior to each function call).

EDIT:
I thought briefly I'd found a solution here: [Using array init list as temporary in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458883/using-array-init-list-as-temporary-in-c11)

The second answer has a conversion from a const array to a (non-const) pointer. In my case this would change the initInstance function call to:

```
const vector<pair<int,int> > initclass::_intvect = initInstance((pair<int,int>*)(const pair<int,int> []){pair<int,int>(1,2), pair<int,int>(3,4), pair<int,int>(5,6), pair<int,int>(7,8), pair<int,int>(9,10)}, NINT);
```

This compiles, but the initInstance function never gets called, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a better way. You can remove that awful function, which does nothing useful. You can initialize vector like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>




struct A
{
    const static std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > intvect;
};

const std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > A::intvect{ std::pair<int,int>(1,2), std::pair<int,int>(3,4), 
                                                   std::pair<int,int>(5,6), std::pair<int,int>(7,8), 
                                                   std::pair<int,int>(9,10) };

int main()
{
    (void) A::intvect;
}
```

This is using the c++11 7th constructor of [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) - the one with taking initializer list.

Comment: This is a minimal example: I need the vector to be a static class member. I can't include the call to the vector constructor in the main function. I could replace my initInstance call with a call to this constructor, but this constructor is part of C++11, which I'd rather not use.