# Array literal syntax quirks

Tags: c++, c++11

When I am using array literals I am seeing weird behavior on different compilers.

The first problem I face is when I have a program like this:

```c++
void f(int*)
{
}

int main()
{
    using T = int[];
    f(T{1, 2, 3});
}
```

On [Clang 3.5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a89215c0267552e1) this compiles fine, but on [g++ 4.9](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71bffcf9ee06808e) it gives the error:

```c++
source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source_file.cpp:8:17: error: taking address of temporary array
     f(T{1, 2, 3});
```

In [VC++](http://rextester.com/RQTY16956) it gives the error:

```c++
Process exit code is not 0: 255
```

So that's weird.

If I make `T` equal to `int[3]` instead of `int[]`, it will compile fine on [VC++](http://rextester.com/VUCC64069) but still gives the same error on g++.

Also, if I change the code to:

```c++
using T = int[];
int* x = T{1, 2, 3};
```

then clang gives an error similar to g++.

Which compiler is right?

---

I figured out how to make it work on [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79fcc348ff1078e5) by making the parameter of `f` be `int (&&)[3]` but in [VC++](http://rextester.com/VKW32133) it gives a different error.

Comment: Related: [Using array init list as temporary in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458883/using-array-init-list-as-temporary-in-c11)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clang is right. Constructing the array object is well-formed after [expr.type.conv]/3, and we are not taking the adress of the array object (as GCC says) but let an array-to-pointer decay happen, which is allowed for arrays no matter the value category:

> An lvalue **or rvalue** of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound
>   of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result
>   is a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit String literals are lvalues.

Comment: Ah, dammit. As an aside (because I acknowledge you're definitely right in this), do you know where the standard says so? 2.14.5/8 gives us the type, but...