# Call webassembly from embedded v8 without JS

Tags: c++, v8, webassembly

I would like to use webassembly directly from my embedded v8 without the detour via JavaScript. I used the provided [hello-world example](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/samples/hello-world.cc) and the [WasmModuleObjectBuilderStreaming](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/include/v8.h#L4522) class from `v8.h`. However, I am stuck at how to extract the `add` function. Help would be appreciated.

```
#include <include/v8.h>

#include <include/libplatform/libplatform.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using v8::HandleScope;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Promise;
using v8::WasmModuleObjectBuilderStreaming;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
  v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
  std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
  v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
  v8::V8::Initialize();
  Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
  create_params.array_buffer_allocator = v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);
  Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
  HandleScope scope(isolate);

  WasmModuleObjectBuilderStreaming stream(isolate);

  // Use the v8 API to generate a WebAssembly module.
  //
  // |bytes| contains the binary format for the following module:
  //
  //     (func (export "add") (param i32 i32) (result i32)
  //       get_local 0
  //       get_local 1
  //       i32.add)
  //
  // taken from: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/samples/hello-world.cc#L66
  std::vector<uint8_t> wasmbin {
          0x00, 0x61, 0x73, 0x6d, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x07, 0x01,
          0x60, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x01, 0x7f, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x07,
          0x07, 0x01, 0x03, 0x61, 0x64, 0x64, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x01,
          0x07, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x20, 0x01, 0x6a, 0x0b
  };

  // write bytes and finish
  stream.OnBytesReceived(wasmbin.data(), wasmbin.size());
  stream.Finish();
  Local<Promise> promise = stream.GetPromise();

  // TODO: Get exports, extract `add` & call `add`
}
```

**Build setup:**

Follow the instruction in *Run the example* from the official [Getting started with embedding V8](https://v8.dev/docs/embed#run-the-example). Save the code to *sample/wasm.cc* and execute following commands:

```
$ g++ -I. -O2 -Iinclude samples/wasm.cc -o wasm  -lv8_monolith -Lout.gn/x64.release.sample/obj/ -pthread -std=c++17`
$ ./wasm`
```

**Solution:**

Thanks [@liliscent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53929545), I adapted my example accordingly. Because we all like, working code:

```
#include <include/v8.h>

#include <include/libplatform/libplatform.h>

using v8::HandleScope;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Promise;
using v8::WasmModuleObjectBuilderStreaming;
using v8::WasmCompiledModule;
using v8::Context;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Value;
using v8::String;
using v8::Object;
using v8::Function;
using v8::Int32;
using args_type = Local<Value>[];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
  v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
  std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
  v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
  v8::V8::Initialize();
  Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
  create_params.array_buffer_allocator = v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);
  Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
  HandleScope scope(isolate);
  Local<Context> context = Context::New(isolate);
  Context::Scope context_scope(context);

  WasmModuleObjectBuilderStreaming stream(isolate);

  // Use the v8 API to generate a WebAssembly module.
  //
  // |bytes| contains the binary format for the following module: //
  //     (func (export "add") (param i32 i32) (result i32)
  //       get_local 0
  //       get_local 1
  //       i32.add)
  //
  // taken from: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/samples/hello-world.cc#L66
  std::vector<uint8_t> wasmbin {
          0x00, 0x61, 0x73, 0x6d, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x07, 0x01,
          0x60, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x7f, 0x01, 0x7f, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x07,
          0x07, 0x01, 0x03, 0x61, 0x64, 0x64, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x01,
          0x07, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x20, 0x01, 0x6a, 0x0b
  };

  // same as calling:
  // let module = new WebAssembly.Module(bytes);
  Local<WasmCompiledModule> module = WasmCompiledModule::DeserializeOrCompile(isolate,
      WasmCompiledModule::BufferReference(0, 0),
      WasmCompiledModule::BufferReference(wasmbin.data(), wasmbin.size())
      ).ToLocalChecked();

  // same as calling:
  // let module_instance_exports = new WebAssembly.Instance(module).exports;
  args_type instance_args{module};
  Local<Object> module_instance_exports = context->Global()
    ->Get(context, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "WebAssembly"))
    .ToLocalChecked().As<Object>()
    ->Get(context, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Instance"))
    .ToLocalChecked().As<Object>()
    ->CallAsConstructor(context, 1, instance_args)
    .ToLocalChecked().As<Object>()
    ->Get(context, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "exports"))
    .ToLocalChecked().As<Object>()
    ;

  // same as calling:
  // module_instance_exports.add(77, 88)
  args_type add_args{Int32::New(isolate, 77), Int32::New(isolate, 88)};
  Local<Int32> adder_res = module_instance_exports
    ->Get(context, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "add"))
    .ToLocalChecked().As<Function>()
    ->Call(context, context->Global(), 2, add_args)
    .ToLocalChecked().As<Int32>();

  printf("77 + 88 = %d\n", adder_res->Value());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess you need to query some environment for the "value" of the `add` symbol. But I have no ideas about how that should be done

Comment: Because the V8 api changes all the time: updated this example to run in V8 version 7.7: https://gist.github.com/jeroen/c5303beb63e478330507c17c66a4632f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a WebAssembly module directly from C++ via `v8::WasmCompiledModule` class (it will be renamed to `v8::WasmModuleObject` in next version):

```
    Local<WasmCompiledModule> module = WasmCompiledModule::DeserializeOrCompile(isolate,
            WasmCompiledModule::BufferReference(0, 0),
            WasmCompiledModule::BufferReference(wasmbin.data(), wasmbin.size())
        ).ToLocalChecked();
```

But AFAIK, v8 doesn't expose its webassembly api directly, you have to get them from JS global context. The following code creates a module instance, and gets the `exports` of the instance:

```
    using args_type = Local<Value>[];

    Local<Object> module_instance_exports = context->Global()
        ->Get(context, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "WebAssembly"))
        .ToLocalChecked().As<Object>()
        ->Get(context, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Instance"))
        .ToLocalChecked().As<Object>()
        ->CallAsConstructor(context, 1, args_type{module})
        .ToLocalChecked().As<Object>()
        ->Get(context, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "exports"))
        .ToLocalChecked().As<Object>()
        ;
```

Then you can get the `add` function from `exports` object and call it:

```
    Local<Int32> adder_res = module_instance_exports
        ->Get(context, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "add"))
        .ToLocalChecked().As<Function>()
        ->Call(context, context->Global(), 2, args_type{Int32::New(isolate, 77), Int32::New(isolate, 88)})
        .ToLocalChecked().As<Int32>();

    std::cout << "77 + 88 = " << adder_res->Value() << "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you @liliscent, that was exactly what I was looking for. I knew that it would not work without using a bit of JS glue code so this is perfect acceptable.
I added your answer to the *solution* section with some fixes for `error: taking address of temporary array` compile errors.

Comment: Actually that `error` is a long-standing GCC bug, the syntax in my answer is valid both for compile and runtime. Clang correctly accepts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458883/using-array-init-list-as-temporary-in-c11#comment24292271_15458897 But it's good to make gcc happy...

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in the [Wasm C/C++ API proposal](https://github.com/rossberg/wasm-c-api), which allows using a Wasm engine directly from C/C++. The design of this API is independent of any particular engine, but the proposal contains a more or less complete prototype implementation on top of V8.

Sample snippet (see e.g. [hello.cc](https://github.com/rossberg/wasm-c-api/blob/master/example/hello.cc)):

```
// ...
auto engine = wasm::Engine::make();
auto store = wasm::Store::make(engine.get());
auto module = wasm::Module::make(store.get(), binary);
auto instance = wasm::Instance::make(store.get(), module.get(), imports);
auto exports = instance->exports();
exports[0]->func()->call();
```

Comment: Awesome, I came across your project while searching for the answer definitively interesting. I still have to figure out how you interact with v8.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. V8 natively supports C-API since 2019: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/src/wasm/c-api.cc